# Load XmlDocument/Document object from local XML file in Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, typescript, winjs

I'm currently porting a WinJS JavaScript/Typescript Windows 10 Universal app to Apache Cordova. In the Windows 10 WinJS app, loading local XML files worked well and very fast in the following way:

```js
private loadXmlAsync(version: Version): WinJS.Promise<Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument> {
      return new WinJS.Promise((complete, error, progress) => {
          Utility.getVerifiedUriAsync(version.fileName).then((uri) => { 
              Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).then((file) => {
                  Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.loadFromFileAsync(file).then((doc) => {
                      complete(doc);
                  });
              });
          });
      });
  }
```

Giving a Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument object upon loading the local XML file.

Now in porting this functionality to Apache Cordova, I have made the following solution work:

```js
function loadXmlAsync(fileName: string): WinJS.Promise<Document> {
    return new WinJS.Promise((complete, error, progress) => {
        getVerifiedUriAsync(fileName).done((uri) => {
            (window as any).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(uri,
                (f: FileEntry) => {
                    f.file((file) => {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = (evt) => {
                            var parsedXml = new DOMParser().parseFromString((evt.target as any).result, "text/xml");
                            complete(parsedXml);
                        }
                        reader.onerror = (evt) => {
                            error(evt.target);
                        }
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                    });
                },
                (e) => {
                    error(e);
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

However, this solution is extremely slow, especially in comparison to the almost-instant WinJS/Windows 10 app's solution.
The loss of time occurs in the extremely slow `reader.readAsBinaryString(file)` call. (The `DOMParser().parseFromString()` works well and is relatively fast) (I have also tried `reader.readAsText(file)` and the speed is slow as well)

As such, is there a correct way to load a local XML file in Apache Cordova in a similar manner and speed to that of the Windows 10/WinJS implementation?

Thanks!